# Problem with startup `rc.local` script

Tags: macos, script, startup

Until OS X 10.9 I could also run Bootcamp within Virtualbox (through a .vmdk file). In order to do this, I needed to unmount the Bootcamp partition after changing the permissions during the OS X startup process in the rc.local file. Now, with OS X 10.10 `rc.local` does not seem to work anymore and I cannot start my virtual machine without first manually execute the terminal commands that are in my rc.local script.

Here is my `rc.local` content:

> sudo chmod 777 /dev/disk0s4
>   diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s4

I understood that `rc.local` is not supported anymore in Yosemite and `launchd` should be used instead. Source:: [How To: Run Windows 7 (Bootcamp) in VirtualBox](http://kindlevsmac.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/how-to-run-windows-7-bootcamp-in-virtualbox/).

Can someone help me with a valid script and show me how to use it?

Answer (score 5):

I was using those commands for VirtualBox in rc.local, and I ran into the same problem.  I don't if this is the right way to do this, but it works for me.

I created `/Library/LaunchDaemons/local.localhost.startup.plist` containing the code below.  It runs the rc.local script once at start up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>             <string>local.localhost.startup</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/etc/rc.local</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

That plist isn't quite right, so try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.localhost.startup</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/etc/rc.local</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that rc.local has the permission to execute, via a 
    sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local

The LaunchDaemon does not explicitly report an error, so I was bitten by this until I changed permissions.

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 1):

Since Mac OS X 10.4, startup items such as `/etc/rc.local` file or `/Library/StartupItems` folder are deprecated in favour of `launchd` daemons and agents.<sup>[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html)</sup>

Check [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) documentation page for further details.

For example, here is the example which launches a daemon named `hello`, passing `world` as a single argument and instructs `launchd` to keep the job running:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.hello</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There are two keys in the top level dictionary:

- `Label` - uniquely identifies the job,
- `ProgramArguments` - a value of an array of strings which represent the tokenized arguments and the program to run.

Here is the practical [example to increase system resources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293062/21471).

---

The locations for startup daemons are `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

The location for startup agents are `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` and user’s individual `Library/LaunchAgents` folder.