# How to add startup program using Terminal?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, remote-control

Honestly, I'm finding Apple's [launchctl](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs) and plist (XML?) usage to be somewhat confusing and overkill. Using Terminal, I just wanna say *hey, macOS, start program.app at boot!* or *hey, macOS, start my /path/to/shell.sh at boot!*

**How can I add a boot item --remotely via Terminal/SSH/Netcat/command line/shell?**

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
      Time since boot: 2:03
```

Comment: There's more to it than just a startup program.  Do you want it to launch for only one user, all users or regardless if a user logs in?  See this [primer on `launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271).  Here's another [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296652/119271) on how to run something at boot (no interval)

Comment: My frustration is exactly the same! Why does apple make it so hard to do such simple things? I hope someone could explain to me why this is necessary..

Answer (score 6):

**LaunchDaemons – Run at Boot**

**LaunchAgents – Run at Login**

So... you need a daemon

suggest you to `cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` or any other in the same dir and use it as reference.

Just remove unnecessary. It will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>shell.sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/shell.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

save the file in the same dir, but named `shell.sh.plist` and run

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/shell.sh.plist`

to remove script from the load list:

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/shell.sh.plist`

this is not linux so things are done Mac way.

`man launchd` & `man launchd.plist` will provide all needed info

**OR**

you can use an approach described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153387/problem-with-startup-rc-local-script)

Creating `.plist` just once and pointing it to your startup script which in turn will start anything you add there without need to write new `.plist` every time you want to start something new.

Comment: thanks. im making progress with this. the script requires internet access, how do i tell the plist to execute only after network connectivity has been established?

Comment: This answer is incomplete and will result in failure(s) when the user attempts this.

Comment: @Allan how do you mean?

Comment: @lily - I posted two links in the comments.   The first one is a primer on launchd and creating the plists.  See that.

Comment: @Allan is it possible to add a one-liner script into the plist so avoid sourcing a local file?

Comment: @lily Yes.  You don't need to put a script.  You can issue the command directly with command line arguments.  If you want to see a good example of how to do this at boot time, click the second link in my comments

Comment: @Allan hmm, cant figure out which `<key>` to use. im going to ask a new question, keep an eye out for it, please!

Comment: @Allan, try actually `cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325727/how-to-run-a-one-liner-shell-command-using-launchd

Comment: @lily, can't comment someone else's post yet but should your script monitor online/offline state or it just waits for some time after boot until connection is established? if it's the latter than you can do it quick and dirty by using `sleep <time in seconds>` inside your script or simply `sleep 30 && script.sh` as an outside option

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It took me awhile to make it work: 1. I disabled SIP for me to edit/save in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/. More information can be found in this post (https://superuser.com/questions/1159290/cant-edit-read-only-file-even-when-root/1159330) . 2. I forgot to chmod for the system to run my shell script before hand. The system did not send warnings when that is the case!